# TypeORM: FieldResolver return type err:You need to provide explicit type for

Tags: typescript, typeorm

```
@Resolver(() => Store)
export class StoreResolver {
@FieldResolver()
    async totalFastDelivery(@Root() store: Store): Promise<number> {
        return await getRepository(Order)
            .createQueryBuilder("orders")
            .where("orders.storeId = :id", { id: store.id })
            .andWhere("orders.fastDelivery = true ")
            .getCount();
    }
}
```

Although `getCount()` return type is `Promise<number>`
 get this
`Error: You need to provide explicit type for StoreResolver#totalFastDelivery !`
So whats wrong with it? should i use any other type ?

Answer (score 0):

`@FieldResolver(() => Int)`
would solve it.